# How to stop Auto moving slider

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

my carousel/slider is moving automatically and i wants to stop it that it only moves by clicking the navigation errow, this is the picture of slider https://ibb.co/HPr9rJR its is moving at left side automatically, i wants that it does not automatically and only moves by clicking on "<", ">" it. I get this slider from here

> codepen.io/decibeldesign/details/bMrQKN

code:

> ```
>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs   
>           /twitter- bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css">
>     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1
>           /jquery.min.js"></script>
>
>     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap 
>         /4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> ```

```
                         <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-8 my-5 text-center5">
                            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center">
                               <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                  <a href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                     <div class="carousel-nav-icon">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="height: 50px;">
                                           <path d="m88.6,121.3c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2s2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2c1.6-1.6 1.6-4.2 0-5.8l-51-51 51-51c1.6-1.6 1.6-4.2 0-5.8s-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-54,53.9c-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l54,53.9z"/>
                                        </svg>
                                     </div>
                                  </a>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-6">
                                  <!--Start carousel-->
                                  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">                             
                                     <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                                           <div class="row">
                                              <div style="" class="col-12 col-md d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn">
                                                    <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" 
                                                    style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                        <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;">subject</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div style="" class="col-12 col-md d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 upcoming-btn">
                                                    <span href="" class="btn btn-success btn-lg dashboard-icon" 
                                                    style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                        <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;">subject</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Upcoming</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                           <div class="row">
                                              <div style="" class="col-12 col-md d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 completed-btn">
                                                    <span href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg dashboard-icon" 
                                                    style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                        <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;">subject</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Completed</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                              <div style="" class="col-12 col-md d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 completed-btn">
                                                    <span href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg dashboard-icon" 
                                                    style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                                        <p style="padding-top: 15px; font-size: 25px;
                                                        font-weight: bold;">subject</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">date</p>
                                                        <p style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold;">Completed</p>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                           </div>
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <!--End carousel-->
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><a  href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
                                  <div class="carousel-nav-icon">
                                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="height: 50px;">
                                        <path d="m40.4,121.3c-0.8,0.8-1.8,1.2-2.9,1.2s-2.1-0.4-2.9-1.2c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8l51-51-51-51c-1.6-1.6-1.6-4.2 0-5.8 1.6-1.6 4.2-1.6 5.8,0l53.9,53.9c1.6,1.6 1.6,4.2 0,5.8l-53.9,53.9z"/>
                                     </svg>
                                  </div>
                                  </a>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: put `interval: false` into carousel js config. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#options

Comment: This question need to be improved with the brief information.

Comment: @CertainPerformance plz chk the updated question

Comment: @Kevin plz check the updated question

Comment: @demkovych plz check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your .js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

Comment: please put this code in footer before closing the body tag or put in the <script></script> tag its working for my end

Answer (score 0):

Easy bro, you should add:

```
data-interval="false"
```

In your element.
Please next time check the documentation.

Comment: file are online library files how an i do it , and plz check the updated question